# Validate objects in JSON array with Ajv

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

I am trying to validate if the "actions" array has specific objects. Each object can have their own properties, depending on the type property. The actions array can have multiple occurences from these type of objects, not just one.

My JSON:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "X",
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2,
            "c": 3
        },
        {
            "type": "Y",
            "d": 1,
            "e": 2,
            "f": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

In this example the object that has type = X has required properties as a, b, c. The object type Y in the array has required properties d, e, f.

I am trying to validate this with the switch keyword:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "actions"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "actions": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "switch": [
                    {
                        "if": {
                            "properties": {
                                "type": {
                                    "pattern": "^X$"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "then": {
                            "required": [
                                "a",
                                "b",
                                "c"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "if": {
                            "properties": {
                                "type": {
                                    "pattern": "^Y$"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "then": {
                            "required": [
                                "d",
                                "e",
                                "f"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
    }
}
```

But still I could not figure out how to use the switch keyword to validate objects of arrays where each object type is specified by a property in the object so the object type can be identified with a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema looks almost ok, you may need one last `{then: false}` subschema inside "switch", as without it if the "type" property is neither 'X' nor 'Y' the validation will succeed.

Also, instead of using `{pattern: '^X$'}` you can use `{enum: ['X']}` or even `{constant: 'X'}` (in draft-06 it is "const"); instead of using switch you can use "if/then/else" (from [ajv-keywords](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv-keywords), it is likely to be included in draft-07) or even "select", that may be more suitable for such scenario.

Maybe you can clarify the last question, I don't think I understand.

Comment: I added that then false subschema. It is still not able to validate the json if I remove the property 'a'. It says valid.

Comment: ok thanks, the issue was that I used 5.0.3-beta instead of 4.x.

Comment: You can use beta, but then "switch" should be added from ajv-keywords. See migration guide: https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/releases/tag/5.0.1-beta.0